# Animate only background-position X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate the background-position X axis but leave the Y axis as 'bottom'.

I have been able to animate the X axis using:

```
$('#imageholder').animate({'background-position' : mousePosX});
```

However, this resets the Y position which on my CSS file is set as `bottom`.

I have tried combining `mousePosX` and `bottom`, eg:

```
$('#heroimageholder').animate({'background-position' : mousePosXPercent + " bottom"});
```

or:

```
var bgpos = mousePosXPercent + " bottom";
$('#heroimageholder').animate({'background-position' : bgpos});
```

With no results.

Is there a way to make `.animate()` work with multiple css values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this particular issue could be remedied using `background-position-x`, eg:

```
$('#imageholder').animate({'background-position-x' : mousePosX});
```